# What is this bush/tree?

Tags: identification

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help us identifying this large bush on our backyard, possibly something planted by previous owners. I was thinking of some kind of a hydrangea, but I'm far from certain (read somewhere hydrangea should have more stamens). The bush is about 3 meters high, I would say.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What part of the world is the shrub in?

Answer (score 2):

It seems [Viburnum lantana (wayfarer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viburnum_lantana), or any other Viburnum.